# Answer $9^x = 4^x + 6^x$ to a 10th grader, who knows math until the equation of a straight line (just before calculus)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

> Find $x$:
> $$9^x = 4^x + 6^x$$

This was in my exam today, and I have no idea, would really help if someone taught me, I would love to know how to write math on this website and is there a way to like search a topic for a 10th grader where i can find many questions and solve them?

Comment: The general question of solving for $x$ in $a^x+b^x=c^x$ where $a,b,c$ are just arbitrary numbers like $3^x+5^x=7^x$ or $11^x+11^x=12^x$ or other examples... this general question is *not* solvable using "simple" or "elementary" methods.  As a tenth grader you are *not* expected to be able to solve random problems like this.  Even experts would need to rely on things like the Lambert-W function (a non-elementary function which is particularly ugly and difficult to use in practice) or numerical methods.

Comment: @JMoravitz Actually, this case is transformable into a quadratic.

Comment: If you were given a problem like this, it was either a mistake, or they expected you to be able to find it by inspection or some special property specific to these particular numbers.  We can tell right away that there should *be* an answer since both functions are monotonic increasing and at $x=1$ you have $4^x+6^x=4^1+6^1=10$ while $9^x=9^1=9$ is less than that, while later at $x=2$ you have $4^2+6^2=16+36=52$ while $9^2=81$ is more than that, so the answer should be somewhere between $1$ and $2$, but that the answer can't be a whole number since left would be odd while right is even.

Comment: @JMoravitz Because $6$ is the geometric mean of $4$ and $9$, this particular case does have a solution for example  if you let $y=\left(\frac32\right)^x$.  Familiarity with logarithms might help express this solution

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you sir, just know that I appreciate you and aspire to become like you(very good in maths and physics) one day

Comment: @Henry Sir can you maybe provide the solution? And also can you tell me what is a monotonic function? I know logarithms I did it in class 9th.

Comment: monotonic (increasing) just means that it only grows and doesn't ever turn around.

Comment: @JMoravitz thank u sir

Comment: As for your later questions , the answer is Yes. You can find questions (and read nice answers) by searching them under appropriate tags of your convenient level.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3625366/42969 and the linked questions – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%249%5Ex%20%3D%204%5Ex%20%2B%206%5Ex%24)

Comment: See also [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265/42969), in particular [How to search with Approach0](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29267/42969).

Answer (score 37):

$$9^x = 4^x + 6^x$$

Dividing by $4^x$ , we get :

$$\left(\frac{9}{4}\right)^x =  1 + \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^x$$

$$\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2x} =  1 + \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{x}$$

Substituting $\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^x = t $
, you get a quadratic equation in $t$,
$$t^2 =  1 + t$$

Now, solve for $t$ and then solve for $x$.

Comment: +1. How did you know, or forebode, to divide by $4^x$?  I failed to think up this key step!

Comment: Because √9/4 = 6/4

Comment: @memeguy Even if you don't divide , you'll get to that eventually. Let $X=2^x$ and $Y=3^x$. Then the equation is $Y^2=XY+X^2$ and now solve one variable for another by quadratic formula.